# Open file in an external editor from within IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

How can you open a file in an external editor from within IntelliJ IDEA? Is it possible without a plugin?

N.B.: My main motivation is that the "Add Data Source" dialog is stupidly modal so I cannot simply copy and paste the URL, name and password from my configuration file, so I need to open the `application.properties` or `helm\values.yml` in an external editor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In IntelliJ menu, go to `File` | `Settings` | `Tools` | `External Tools`.
2. Click on the `+` button to add a new external tool:

   [image]
3. Fill in the parameters:

   | Parameter | Value |
   | --- | --- |
   | Program | path-to-your-external-editor, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe` |
   | Arguments | `$FilePath$` |
   | Working directory | `$ProjectFileDir$` |

   [image]
4. Select the requested file, right button, `External Tools` | your-external-editor:

   [image]